# Powershell script to Get Objectid of a member in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I want to get the object id of a member in a group not all the object id's of a members in a group, i am using below command

```
Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "00438306-7g37-4638-a72d-0ee890017680
```

I am using powershell; what is the query to get the particular member object id in a group Azure Active Directory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0

Answer (score 1):

To get the particular member object id in a group Azure Active Directory, use the below command

```cs
 Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "test@tenant.com"
```

This command gets the specified user.

[image]

Comment: Hey Hi, trying the above Get-AzureADUser command,  Error occurred while executing GetUser 
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. So what permissions does this required pls let me knnow ASAP Thank you..

Comment: Please check whether you have given [required permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: Wha tis the role you have for your Azure subscription?

Comment: Contributor Role

Comment: Run as Administrator -> Sign in with admin account to run azure ad cmdlets and check once